# Remove part of multiline string after pattern in r

Tags: r

I am trying to remove all the characters from ROW FORMAT SERDE, with the gsub function however it does not work. Any suggestion.

```
x <- c("CREATE TABLE `cld_ml_bi_eng.iris`(", "  `sepal_length` double, ", 
  "  `sepal_width` double, ", "  `petal_length` double, ", "  `petal_width` double, ", 
  "  `species` string)", "ROW FORMAT SERDE ", "  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' ", 
  "STORED AS INPUTFORMAT ", "  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' ", 
  "OUTPUTFORMAT ", "  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'", 
  "LOCATION", "  'hdfs://haprod/warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/cld_ml_bi_eng.db/iris'", 
  "TBLPROPERTIES (", "  'bucketing_version'='2', ", "  'transactional'='true', ", 
  "  'transactional_properties'='default', ", "  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1636686825')")
```

Here I use gsub

```
gsub(pattern = "(ROW FORMAT SERDE).*", replacement = "\\1", x = x)
```

**My expected output**

```
c("CREATE TABLE `cld_ml_bi_eng.iris`(", "  `sepal_length` double, ", 
  "  `sepal_width` double, ", "  `petal_length` double, ", "  `petal_width` double, ", 
  "  `species` string)")
```

Comment: Each of your lines is a separate object - you either need to paste it together first for `gsub` to work, or just select the chunk - `head(x, grep("ROW FORMAT SERDE\\s+", x)-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use `grep` to find the index of the string in your input vector which starts with the text `ROW FORMAT SERDE`.  Then, subset the input vector and paste into a single string:

```r
paste0(x[1:(grep("^ROW FORMAT SERDE", x)-1)], collapse="")
```

> [1] "CREATE TABLE `cld_ml_bi_eng.iris`(  `sepal_length` double,   `sepal_width` double,   `petal_length` double,   `petal_width` double,   `species` string)"